# Word Choice: Besides vs In addition to?

Tags: word-choice

1. Besides engineering, I should also get some grammar lessons
2. In addition to engineering, I should also get some grammar lessons.

In my interpretation

#1 means that engineering already includes grammar

whereas in #2 there's no such implication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  "Besides" in this context is saying that engineering *isn't* including grammar.  You're implying they are separate things.

"In addition to" also implies they are separate things.  In fact the meaning is very similar here.

If I had to say there is a difference, it is that "besides" can be used to change argument.  So "Besides engineering..." might imply you were trying to change topic to grammar, as opposed to "In addition to engineering..." which is referring to simply *more* classes.